# How to get all documents but one from firebase firestore in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Since I can't use `!=`, I''m using `<` and `>` but I don't know how to merge them together and await the result. It works for only one at a time.

```
  async getAllUsersExceptCurrent() {
    const lower = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .where(
        firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
        '<',
        firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      )
      .get();

    const upper = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .where(
        firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
        '>',
        firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
      )
      .get();

    const usersList = await lower.then(snapshot => {
      return snapshot.docs.map(user => {
        console.log(user.data());
        return { id: user.id, username: user.data().username };
      });
    });

    return usersList;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
    async getAllUsersExceptCurrent() {
            const lower = firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .where(
                    firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
                    '<',
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
                )
                .get();

            const upper = firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('users')
                .where(
                    firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
                    '>',
                    firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
                )
                .get();

            const [l, u] = await Promise.all([lower, upper]);

            const lArray = l.docs.map(user => {
                return { id: user.id, username: user.data().username };
            });

            const uArray = u.docs.map(user => {
                return { id: user.id, username: user.data().username };
            });

            return lArray.concat(uArray);
        }
```

---

The following would also work:

```
    //...
    const results = await Promise.all([lower, upper, lower]);

    const usersList = [];
    results.forEach(r => {
      r.docs.map(user => {
        usersList.push({ id: user.id, username: user.data().username });
      });
    });
    return usersList;
```